# Predict flight delays with RNN

Tags: tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use rnn to predict flight delay 
[image]

here is dataset website : https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Tables.asp?DB_ID=120&DB_Name=Airline%20On-Time%20Performance%20Data&DB_Short_Name=On-Time

x_train.shape = (75395, 16) 
x_test.shape = (32313, 16)

**I need to build RNN model to predict flight delays .**

here is my notebook
https://github.com/AhmadAbdElhameed/flight_delays/blob/master/Flight%20Delay.ipynb
(go to cell 83) - for rnn model

**I need help to create rnn model to predict delay**

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: question updated